# Equivalent of C/C++ for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

What will be the python equivalent to this simple C++ code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    for (j = 10; j > i; j--)
     {  
       a[i]*a[j];
     }
  }
```

Especially I am having problem in the implementation of the second loop with 'j' using

```
j > i
```

condition

Comment: It's strange that how my question suddenly get's -1 and also some previous questions being suddenly downvoted....selfish people here ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a while loop in the inner loop to make it slighlty more intuitive and readable:

```
for i in range(10):
    j = 10
    while j > i:
        ...
        j -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the most elegant and useful answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative step with `range()` :

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10, i, -1): # from 10 down to i+1 using range(start,stop,step)
        # Your code
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) docs:

> ```
> class range(start, stop[, step])
> ```
>
> For a *positive step*, the contents of a range r are determined by the
>   formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.
>
> For a *negative step*, the contents of the range are still determined by
>   the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, but the constraints are `i >= 0` and
>   `r[i] > stop`.

Translation inline.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)  //    for i in range(10):
  {
    for (j = 10; j > i; j--)  //    for j in range(10, i, -1):
     {  
       a[i]*a[j];                       a[i] * a[j]; # a[i] *= a[j];  ?
     }
  }
```

Comment: thanks this works...I had doubts between > and '>='  . Now I suppose if the condition was " j >= i "  then I just need to make " for j in range(10, i-1, -1):  "